# Why select function is not blocked in linux

Tags: c, linux

I use select() to block the serial port.
And I input a message to serial port,
Then I receive like this.
In my mind, I think it will print once, but in fact, it print continuously.
So where do I do wrongly?
[serial port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IujCq.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int fd_se;
fd_set readfs;

int set_opt(int fd,int nSpeed, int nBits, char nEvent, int nStop)
{
    struct termios newtio,oldtio;
    if  ( tcgetattr( fd,&oldtio)  !=  0)
    {
        perror("SetupSerial 1");
        return -1;
    }
    bzero( &newtio, sizeof( newtio ) );
    newtio.c_cflag  |=  CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;

    switch( nBits )
    {
    case 7:
        newtio.c_cflag |= CS7;
        break;
    case 8:
        newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;
        break;
    }

    switch( nEvent )
    {
    case 'O':                     
        newtio.c_cflag |= PARENB;
        newtio.c_cflag |= PARODD;
        newtio.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);
        break;
    case 'E':                     
        newtio.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);
        newtio.c_cflag |= PARENB;
        newtio.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
        break;
    case 'N':                   
        newtio.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        break;
    }

switch( nSpeed )
{
    case 2400:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B2400);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B2400);
        break;
    case 4800:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B4800);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B4800);
        break;
    case 9600:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B9600);
        break;
    case 38400:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B38400);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B38400);
        break;
    case 115200:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B115200);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B115200);
        break;
    default:
        cfsetispeed(&newtio, B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&newtio, B9600);
        break;
}
if( nStop == 1 )
{
    newtio.c_cflag &=  ~CSTOPB;
}
else if ( nStop == 2 )
{
    newtio.c_cflag |=  CSTOPB;
}
newtio.c_cc[VTIME]  = 0;
newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);
if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio))!=0)
{
    perror("com set error");
    return -1;
}
printf("set done!\n");
return 0;
}

int open_port(int i)
{
    char *dev[]={"/dev/ttySAC0","/dev/ttySAC1","/dev/ttySAC2","/dev/ttySAC3"};
    long vdisable;
    int fd;
    fd = open( dev[i], O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NDELAY);
    if (-1 == fd)
    {
        printf("Can't Open Serial Port %s\n",dev[i]);
        return(-1);
    }
    else
        printf("Open Serial Port %s success!\n",dev[i]);
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)<0)
    {
        printf("fcntl failed!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
         printf("fcntl id is %d\n",fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0));
    if(isatty(STDIN_FILENO)==0)
    {
        printf("standard input is not a terminal device\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("This is a terminal device\n");
        return fd;
    }

void *serial_function(void *args)
{



    while(1)
    {
        FD_SET(fd_se, &readfs);  /* set testing for source 1 */
        select(fd_se+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(fd_se,&readfs))
        {
            printf("serial_function is running\n");

        }   
    }
       close(fd_se);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    if((fd_se=open_port(1))<0)
    {
        perror("open_port error");
        return;
    }
    if((i=set_opt(fd_se,38400,8,'N',1))<0)
    {
        perror("set_opt error");
        return;
    }

    pthread_t thread1;
    if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, serial_function, NULL) != 0)
    {
         perror("Thread create failed!");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Use the return value you get from `select()`. It can be -1, 0 or the number of readable filedescriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're notified that that file has data ready for reading, but then you don't read that. Of course, the next time you ask, the file *still* has data ready for reading.

The `select()` function doesn't track the actual data to know if it's already notified for it or not. As long as the file is readable, it will report as being readable.

To clear it, read out the data.

Also, as pointed out in another answer, you should clear the file descriptor set before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You must reset to zero your set each loop

```
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_SET(fd_se, &readfs);  /* set testing for source 1 */
    select(fd_se+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (FD_ISSET(fd_se,&readfs))
    {
        printf("serial_function is running\n");

    }   
}
```

Moreover you must read data available to make the `FD` not "ready to be read"

Comment: The first time i add FD_ZERO(&readfs); . It didn't work. And then I read the message, It did work. Thanks

Comment: I delete FD_ZERO(&readfs);. It still did work. So the main reason I think is that I  do not read the message.

Comment: Actually you do not need it because of you are using a single FD. In a near future, if you'll use many FD and for each iteration you want to change the set you will need it. BTW, yes, in your specific case read the data from FD it's enough.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant for roov

Comment: @LPs Actually, I am trying to build a project which include socket and serial. I create a thread  to detect serial and run socket in main thread.  I feel confused to use select() to coordinate the two relationship

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value you get from select. The fd_sets  contain valid bitmasks **only if this return value is greater than zero**. Otherwise, they are undefined (but probably unchanged in linux).
The return from `select()` indicates:

- `-1` : error condition. But beware: not all conditions are errors: `EAGAIN` and `EALARM` indicate the occurence of an event other than a status change in one of the fd_sets. For network sockets, there are also some other non-fatalresource_temporarily_unavailable conditions possible.
- `0` : timeout : the time given in the last argument to `select()` is exceeded (this cannot happen in this particular case because the last argument is NULL)
- `>= 1` one or more of the file descriptors are readable or writeable. (this means: you can read() or write() them without blocking) Check the bits in the fd_sets to find out which fds to read/write

---

```
#include <errno.h>

while(1)
{
    int rc;
    char buff[16];

    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_SET(fd_se, &readfs);  /* set testing for source 1 */
    rc = select(fd_se+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (rc == -1) switch (errno) {
        default:
          fprintf(stderr,"Err=%d\n", errno);
        case EAGAIN: // EINTR
          continue; // try again ...
        }
    if (rc == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Timeout\n");
        continue;
        }
        /* rc must be >= 1, now ... */
    if (FD_ISSET(fd_se,&readfs))
    {
        printf("serial_function is running\n");
        rc = read(fd_se, buff, sizeof buff);
                /* handle EOF */
        if (!rc) break;
                /* handle error */
        if (rc < 0) break;
        // ... do something useful with the received data
    }
}
```